# How to rename a zip file after an HTML file in a Gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am attempting to zip up all files in my dist folder using gulp-zip and would like to dynamically name the zip file after the only html file in that directory. Here's my attempt using gulp-filenames, but have had no luck.

```js
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');
var filenames = require('gulp-filenames');

gulp.task('zipp', function(){
 gulp.src('dist/*')
   .pipe(zip('_final.zip'))
   .pipe(rename({prefix:getHtmlName()}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
})

function getHtmlName(){
 gulp.src("./src/*.html")
 .pipe(filenames("html"))
 .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
 return filenames.get("html");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');
const filenames = require('gulp-filenames');

// run the getHTMLname task first, filenames will then have the data stored in an array

gulp.task('zipp', ['getHTMLname'], function () {

    return gulp.src('dist/*')
    .pipe(zip('_final.zip'))

    // rename gets the file passing through it, in this case '_final.zip'

    .pipe(rename(function (path) {

      // retrieve the array of string filenames, use the first and only one in the array
      // and get the basename via split

      path.basename = filenames.get("html")[0].split('.')[0] + path.basename;
    }))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
})

gulp.task('getHTMLname', function () {
  return gulp.src("./dist/*.html")
    .pipe(filenames("html"))
});

//  **************************************************************

const gulp = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');

const glob = require("glob");
const path = require('path');

gulp.task('zipp', function () {

  return gulp.src('dist/*')
    .pipe(zip('_final.zip'))

    .pipe(rename(function (file) {

      // glob.sync returns an array, get the first member of that array
      // path.basename('string', '.html') returns the name of the file without the extension

      var temp = path.basename(glob.sync("./dist/*.html")[0], '.html');
      file.basename = temp + file.basename;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

If you really want to use gulp-filenames, use the code above the ********'s. The 'getHTMLname' task must run first - that is when gulp-filenames builds its array of file names from whatever source directory you feed it.  That array can later be used anywhere in a subsequent task.

However, I recommend the second method using glob and path modules, which you should learn anyway.  The second method does not require a separate task, it just gets, globs, the html filename you want right in the same task so it is simpler.  Also when I installed gulp-filenames it is using a ton of deprecated modules so it badly needs to be updated.  It works now but may not as you update node, etc.

Comment: That's excellent! I had attempted using `fs.readdirSync` but had to loop through the directory to match the html. This is so much better. Thanks Mark!